# Ordering row number sequentially for columns that have same values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

| No. | ReferenceNumber | TransactionTime | Amount | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3099 | N/A | -1125 | A |
| 2 | 3099 | N/A | -1125 | B |
| 3 | 3100 | N/A | -375 | B |
| 4 | 3101 | 05:00 | -375 | A |
| 5 | 3101 | 05:00 | 2000 | B |
| 6 | 3101 | 06:00 | 2000 | A |
| 7 | 3102 | 06:00 | 2500 | B |

How to determine a number (in the `No.` column) sequentially for the above data using SQL Server? I appreciate for the help.

I've tried this T-SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ReferenceNumber asc) No., 
    ReferenceNumber, TransactionTime, Amount, Source
FROM 
    aTable
```

I got the result like this:

| No. | ReferenceNumber | TransactionTime | Amount | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3099 | N/A | -1125 | A |
| 2 | 3099 | N/A | -375 | B |
| 3 | 3100 | N/A | -1125 | B |
| 4 | 3101 | 05:00 | -375 | A |
| 5 | 3101 | 05:00 | 2000 | B |
| 6 | 3101 | 06:00 | 2500 | B |
| 7 | 3102 | 06:00 | 2000 | A |

But, it's not the expectation like the above table.

Comment: Are you sure? The Amount for RefNbr 3099 and Source B wouldn't suddenly switch from -1125 to -375 unless the table was updated. Regardless, you may want to add Time to your order by windows function.

Comment: Ordem needs to be somehow unique as tables are unsorted by nature the result will be also unsorted when the numbers are the same

Comment: The problem is your `order by` condition is not deterministic. Take `ReferenceNumber` 3101 for example. There are three rows there. If you're only specifying the `order by` as `ReferenceNumber`, which row is supposed to come first? The one with an amount of -375? The one at 06:00? The one with amount 2000? SQL is going to pick that order for you essentially randomly. If you want a deterministic order, you need to provide enough `order by` conditions to sort the data deterministically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this approach

```
CREATE TABLE #Transactions([No.] int identity(1, 1), ReferenceNumber INT
  ,TransactionTime Varchar(15), Amount int, Source Varchar(1))    ;

INSERT into #Transactions
SELECT ReferenceNumber, TransactionTime, Amount, Source
FROM aTable;

SELECT * FROM #Transactions
```

Comment: It helps me a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (No INT, ReferenceNumber INT, TransactionTime TIME, Amount INT,    Source VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @Table (No, ReferenceNumber, TransactionTime, Amount, Source) VALUES
(1, 3099, NULL   , -1125, 'A'),
(2, 3099, NULL   , -1125, 'B'),
(3, 3100, NULL   , -375 , 'B'),
(4, 3101, '05:00', -375 , 'A'),
(5, 3101, '05:00', 2000 , 'B'),
(6, 3101, '06:00', 2000 , 'A'),
(7, 3102, '06:00', 2500 , 'B');

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ReferenceNumber, TransactionTime, Source)
  FROM @Table;
```

Here we've just added some addition columns to the `ROW_NUMBER` `ORDER`.

| 1 | 3099 |  | -1125 | A | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3099 |  | -1125 | B | 2 |
| 3 | 3100 |  | -375 | B | 3 |
| 4 | 3101 | 05:00:00.0000000 | -375 | A | 4 |
| 5 | 3101 | 05:00:00.0000000 | 2000 | B | 5 |
| 6 | 3101 | 06:00:00.0000000 | 2000 | A | 6 |
| 7 | 3102 | 06:00:00.0000000 | 2500 | B | 7 |